# Disable 3 onClick functions after X seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm still learning the wonders of Javascript and jQuery, and I decided to make a rock paper scissors game. However I want to make this one fun and more interactive than just saying "you win" or "you lose".

I have 3 images: rock, paper, and scissors. When you click on of them, it then changes the image source to another one that makes it seem like it's being selected.

Problem is, when you click one, there is a 2 second moment in which the game tells you if you won, lost, or it was a tie. During that moment, you are still able to click the other images without waiting at all. I would like to disable the click listeners so that you can't do that, until the 2 seconds are over.

JS code:

```
$('#rock').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('src','Images/Result/Red Rock.png');
    $('#rock, #paper, #scissors').prop('disabled', true).delay(2000).prop('disabled', false);
});
$('#paper').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('src','Images/Result/Red Paper.png');
    $('#rock, #paper, #scissors').prop('disabled', true).delay(2000).prop('disabled', false);
});
$('#scissors').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('src','Images/Result/Red Scissors.png');
    $('#rock, #paper, #scissors').prop('disabled', true).delay(2000).prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Live site:

http://goo.gl/3LTmMT

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEXExx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay) will work with only those methods which uses queue based execution like animation related methods(animate()/slideDown etc).

In this case it is better to use timeout

```
$('#rock').click(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', 'Images/Result/Red Rock.png');
    pauseClick();
});
$('#paper').click(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', 'Images/Result/Red Paper.png');
    pauseClick();
});
$('#scissors').click(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', 'Images/Result/Red Scissors.png');
    pauseClick();
});

function pauseClick() {
    var $els = $('#rock, #paper, #scissors').prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $els.prop('disabled', false);
    }, 3000)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works exactly as it should in IE, but not Chrome or Firefox. At first I didn't think it worked at all but IE worked. Any idea why?